# Could not load type 'Sitecore.Form.Submit.ISaveAction' from assembly 'Sitecore.Forms.Core, Version=8.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

Tags: wffm, sitecore-client, upgrade

I have Sitecore 8.2(update 1) site with WFFM 8.2. When i navigate to the Sample form folder `sitecore/System/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Sample form` and click on any form then i got error in popup:

> Could not load type 'Sitecore.Form.Submit.ISaveAction' from assembly
>   'Sitecore.Forms.Core, Version=8.2.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'.

I have all latest dll and config files of WFFM 8.2 and this error i have faced after upgrading my Sitecore from 8.1 to 8.2.

Comment: this sample form is an old form ?

Comment: Sitecore.Form.Core.Submit.ISaveAction interface has been moved to Sitecore.WFFM.Abstractions.Actions.ISaveAction please check here: https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Web%20Forms%20For%20Marketers/Web%20Forms%20For%20Marketers%2081/Web%20Forms%20For%20Marketers%2081%20Initial%20Version/Release%20Notes

Comment: So how can i resolve this issue?

Comment: I asked you something is an old form or a new one?

Comment: yes it is old form, i have created this when site was 8.0

Answer (score 4):

Starting with version 8.1 **Sitecore.Form.Core.Submit.ISaveAction** interface has been moved to **Sitecore.WFFM.Abstractions.Actions.ISaveAction**

Please verify your code if your classes inherits from Sitecore.Form.Core.Submit.ISaveAction

You need to change your submit button to use new action. Please check here how to create a new save action:

https://doc.sitecore.net/web_forms_for_marketers/working_with_actions_and_validations/save_actions/create_a_new_save_action

Comment: The old form which i am using earlier, is there any way in which i can use that form or should i need to recreate the form with new save action?

Comment: You need to change just the save action