# Could not load type 'Sitecore.Form.Submit.ISaveAction' when no Sitecore.Form.Submit.ISaveAction references in my custom save action classes

Tags: wffm

I have a sc 8.2 installed (was previously updated from 7ish) and WFFM 8.2 rev. 180329. When I click on my custom form items(***/sitecore/system/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/forms/pathTo/customFormItem***), I get this error :

`Could not load type 'Sitecore.Form.Submit.ISaveAction' from assembly 'Sitecore.Forms.Core, Version=8.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.`

I am not getting this issue with the ootb examples. I am aware of the Sitecore.Form.Submit.ISaveAction interface being moved away from Sitecore.Form.Core to Sitecore.WFFM.Abstractions.Actions (and also aware of this very similar [question](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/4124/could-not-load-type-sitecore-form-submit-isaveaction-from-assembly-sitecore-f).)

I can confirm that in my code, there are no references for the custom save action to Sitecore.Form.Core.

```
using Sitecore.WFFM.Abstractions.Actions;
namespace Website.Controls.SaveAction
{
    public class SendMail : ISaveAction
...
```

I have looked at the wffm patch files, mines are the ones deployed by the wffm package, so most likely vanilla and I ve also check the showConfig to make sure nothing is overriding it.  I am surely missing something, and I am unaware of what could it be.

Any idea on what else could cause this ?

Comment: What do you mean by "custom form items"? Can you turn raw values on and see if you can select those items then? Can you confirm that the forms that migrated from Sitecore 7 do not have the Save to Database save action in the raw values for save actions?

Comment: I'm confused by what seem like typos in your question? You refer to both Sitecore.Form.Submit.ISaveAction and Sitecore.Form.Core.Submit.ISaveAction interfaces, and also to both Sitecore.WFFM.Actions and Sitecore.WFFM.Abstractions.Actions namespaces.

Comment: @SashaKachanov thank you for the raw value tip. Helped me find out a custom save action linked to an other project of ours that hasnt been updated, so there was a reference of Sitecore.Form.Submit.ISaveAction instead of Sitecore.WFFM.Abstractions.Actions. So I guess my question can be resolve as duplicate to other one. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

In Sitecore, whenever selecting an item throws an exception, switch to raw values and select the item again. This should no longer throw the exception and should allow further investigation into which field has the invalid data that causes the exception.

Save actions are stored in the `Save Actions` field in the `Submit` field section - based on the description there might be a bad value in that field.
[image]